# to lower case in laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

i´m traying to get of my DB to lowercase column data with `model::where`

this is my query:

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::where('name', 'LIKE', "%".$search."%")->get();

        $results = [];

        foreach ($restaurants as $r) {
            $data = array(
                'id' => $r->id,
                'label' => $r->name,
                'value' => $r->name,
                'url' => $r->url,
            );
            array_push($results, $data);
        }
```

i´m traying with this:

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::whereRaw('LOWER(name) = ?', [$search])->get();
```

but return empty results.

How i would can to do this?. In my database it´s all in uppercase i need search in uppercase or lowercase

Thanks for help

Comment: You could use [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) before passing the variable to your statement.

Comment: How about `LOWER(name) LIKE ?, [ "%$search%" ]`? Sidenote: Are you using a case sensitive collation? Those are not really that commonly used

Comment: First thing is you should check the [collations](https://database.guide/what-is-collation-in-databases/#:~:text=In%20database%20systems%2C%20Collation%20specifies,the%20data%20in%20the%20database.&text=Collation%20is%20also%20used%20to,width%20and%20Japanese%20kana%20characters.) of your database they should be set as case insensitive unless you have very specific reason to store case sensitive data, doing this you won't need this type of case conversion.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MySQL, MariaDB or PostgreSQL you could simply use a special version of `LIKE` that does not care for case: `ILIKE`:

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::where('name', 'ILIKE', "%".$search."%")->get();

$results = [];

foreach ($restaurants as $r) {
    $data = array(
        'id' => $r->id,
        'label' => $r->name,
        'value' => $r->name,
        'url' => $r->url,
    );
    array_push($results, $data);
}
```

To be more efficient still you could use a collation on that field (or table, or database) on the database that is case insensitive, so every comparison ever made will be case insensitive (Beware that if you have and primary or unique key with an case insensitive collation you cannot have mulple entries with the same text only varying casing).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::whereRaw('LOWER(`name`) LIKE ? ',[trim(strtolower($search)).'%']);
```

if it's not work just add **->get()** at last query